# if string not in line

Tags: string, if-statement, for-loop

I have a list with a bunch of lines (created from a 'show cdp neighbors detail
from a Cisco switch or router).

I want to perform some processing but only on lines that contain one of the following four strings:

```
important = (
        "show cdp neighbors detail",
        "Device ID: ",
        "IP address: ",
        "Platform: " 
)
```

Right now my iterations work but I am processing over a large number of lines that end up doing nothing.  I simply want to skip over the unimportant lines and do my processing over the four lines lines that contain the data that I need.

What I want to do (in English) is:

```
for line in cdp_data_line:
if any of the lines in 'cdp_data_line' does not contain one of the four strings in 'important', then continue (skip over the line).

After skipping the unwanted lines, then I can test to see which of the four lines I have left and process accordingly: 

if all of the four strings in 'important' is not found in any line of cdp_data_line, the continue

if any of those four strings is found in a line,then process:
elif 'show cdp neighbors detail' in line:
    do something
elif 'Device ID: ' in line:
    do something
elif 'IP address: ' in line:
    do something
elif 'Platform: ' in line:
    do something                   
else:
    sys.exit("Invalid prompt for local hostname - exiting")
```

I am trying to do it like this:
if any(s in line for line in cdp_data_line for s not in important):
            continue

PyCharm says it doesn't know what 's' is, even though I found code snippets
using this technique that work in PyCharm.  Not sure why mine is failing.

There has got to be a succinct way of saying: If string1 or string 2 or string 3 or string 4 is not in cdp_data_line, then skip (continue), otherwise
if I find any of those four strings, do something.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think I figured out what I need to do:  file = ['beef', 'string1', 'veal', 'string2', 'pork', 'string3', 'chicken']
strings = (
    "string1",
    "string2",
    "string3"
)

for line in file:
    if any(s in line for s in strings):
        print("yay!")
    else:
        continue